# Find two real functions $f$ and $g$ such that the only $c$ obtained by applying Cauchy's MVT (on $f,g$) satisfies $f'(c) = 0 = g'(c)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$. The functions $f,g \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ are both continuous in $[a,b]$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$ such that $f(a)\neq f(b)$ and $g(a) \neq g(b)$. By the Cauchy's MVT, $\exists c \in (a,b) \ni f'(c)(g(b)-g(a)) = g'(c)(f(b)-f(a))$. Does there exist $f,g \ni$ the only $c$ satisfies $f'(c) = 0 = g'(c)$?

Comment: The hypotheses of Cauchy MVT usually include $g'\neq 0$. Hardy in his _A Course of Pure Mathematics_ uses another hypothesis which forbids vanishing of $f', g'$ at same point. Removing these restrictions means that you can find examples $f, g$ as desired.

Comment: $f=x^2, g=x^4, a=-1, b=2$, produces $c_1=0, c_2 = \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}$ with $f'(c_1) = 0 = g'(c_1)$ and $f'(c_2) >0, g'(c_2)>0$. So, $c_1$ is not the unique solution. I'm looking for an example with unique solution.